# How scan a string for occurrences of one or two digit integers

Tags: ruby, regex

Using Ruby's `String#scan` I'd like to extract from:

```
"8 12 13.5 145 foobar-123F 0.33 10"
```

these results:

```
['8', '12', '10']
```

but nothing else.

Comment: What about `-12`?

Comment: -12 should not match, sorry, should have specified!

Comment: What happened when you tried writing the code? Your question should ask about a specific problem with it, rather than ask us to write it for you. "[mcve]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 would be good reads.

Comment: Does `-12` not match because it has three digits or represents a negative integer?

Comment: Both, I'll edit to clarify

Comment: I'm guessing that the downvote is because your question is posed as an example. You can use an example to help explain the question, but you should always begin with a precise and complete verbal description of the problem. For example, "Given a string, I would like to extract all substrings of one or two digits that are separated from other characters by one or more spaces". btw, why the rush to select an answer?

Comment: Got it mods, got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a pure regex-based solution:

```
/(?<=\s|\A)\d{1,2}(?=\s|\Z)/
```

This uses positive lookbehind and positive lookahead to check that the group of digits is surrounded only by delimiters.

However what I would do instead is tokenize the string using String#split and filter out the tokens that contain non-digit chars. This would make the code be more readable, in my opinion. Example:

```
s = "8 12 13.5 145 foobar-123F 0.33 10"
s.split.select { |token| token =~ /\A\d{1,2}\Z/ }
=> ["8", "12", "10"]
```

Comment: Thank you this is great!

Comment: It's not necessary, or desirable, to use "edit", "update" or "later edit" tags in the text. Instead, simply put the information where it belongs for readability. We can tell whether something changed, and what it was, by looking at the revision history.

Comment: You could simplify the regex by using negative lookarounds: `"8 12 13.5 145 foobar-123F 0.33 10".scan /(?<!\S)\d{1,2}(?!\S)/ #=> ["8", "12", "10"]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use word boundaries and lookarounds:

```
> "8 12 13.5 145 foobar-123F 0.33 10".scan(/(?<!\.)\b\d{1,2}\b(?!\.)/)
=> ["8", "12", "10"]
```

To exclude negative numbers:

```
> "8 12 13.5 145 foobar-123F 0.33 10 -12".scan(/(?<![.\-])\b\d{1,2}\b(?!\.)/)
=> ["8", "12", "10"]
```